# How to combine Oracle RAC with in-memory database to isloate OLAP from OLTP

Tags: oracle, rac, olap

I am going through a document
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/options/database-in-memory-data-sheet-2338744.pdf

There is a thing written "Oracle Real Application Clusters (RAC) can be combined with Oracle Database InMemory to isolate analytic workloads from OLTP workloads by running them on different
servers of a cluster"
Can anyone explain how would it be possible as RAC has the same storage under it and how can different nodes take responsibility of OLAP and OLTP workload independently

Answer (score 0):

RAC has shared storage, but workload can be segregated using different service names for each. Create an OLTP service name for that workload and only run the service on nodes to be used for OLTP processing. Same for analytic workloads.

Comment: would it be possible for a single database running on RAC? Can you please give an example

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/203074/pmdba Can you explain